# Cast away volatile from fundamental type in C++

Tags: c++

What is the proper syntax (if there even is any) for casting away `volatile` from a fundamental type?

Suppose I have the following code:

```
void Bar(const int& x) {}
volatile int foo;

int main() {
    Bar(const_cast<int>(foo));   // (1)
    Bar(const_cast<int&>(foo));  // (2)
    Bar(const_cast<int&&>(foo)); // (3)
    Bar((int)foo);               // (4)
}
```

The C++-style cast in (1) produces an error in VS 2015, but not in gcc 7 with `-std=c++11`. Judging by the C++ standard, section [expr.const.cast] (5.2.11 in C++11), I tend to agree with VS there, as I don't see what paragraph in that section would allow performing this explicit cast (and paragraph 1 disallows any other explicit conversions).

Now (2) and (3) should be perfectly fine as per the standard; however, if I understand the C++ standard correctly, the result of such a conversion would be a non-volatile reference to the volatile variable, and thus accessing it would result in undefined behavior.

As for the C-style cast in (4), I'm surprised that it doesn't also produce an error in VS 2015, as section [expr.cast] (5.4 in C++11) of the standard appears to explicitly designate such a cast as ill-formed, as it cannot be synthesized using C++-style casts.

Comment: What do you expect (1) to achieve? The value read from `foo` is an int. This cast is redundant. Also, GCC 7.5 does error on (1): https://godbolt.org/z/zvW3E3jWW

Comment: Remember that const lref can implicitly bind to rvalue

Comment: As for (2), (3): Yes, this is UB. What do you want to do really? This is a bit of an XY problem. Maybe you can make Bar a template function.

Comment: _"...Any attempt to refer to a volatile object through a glvalue of non-volatile type (e.g. through a reference or pointer to non-volatile type) results in undefined behavior..."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv

Comment: `Bar` is beyond my control (in the real-life case, it's actually the `find()` method of `std::set`). Without any cast at all, g++ 7 refuses to bind `volatile int` to a `const int&` reference.

Comment: What I want to achieve is to effectively pass the content of `foo` by value.

Comment: Would this be acceptable: `int my_foo = foo;  bar(my_foo); `  ?

Comment: Then create a local variable, assign it the value of the volatile variable and pass that local variable.

Comment: [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? Instead of asking a too generalized question you could ask for your actual use case. Bringing `std::set::find` to the table wont cause more confusion than `Bar` does ;)

Comment: Why have `volatile` anyway?  It has no place in C++ except for a few specialized places none of them to do with thread synchronisation.

Comment: Actually, strike my above comment about what I want to achieve. What I _really_ want to achieve is understand how the compilers' behavior maps to the C++ standard.

Comment: Then please edit this question (or maybe better ask a new one) with a clear question. This question does not show any questionable compiler behavior. (GCC 7 does not allow (1). Maybe it's a bug in a previous version.) Or maybe your question is why (4) does not error?

Comment: (1), (2), (3) are Undefined Behaviour see my comment above.  (4) is `reinterpret_cast` and all bets are off as you it says to the compiler _"I know better than you"_

Comment: @RichardCrittenYes, thread sync is exactly what that variable in the real-life case is volatile for. The section where I'm using it is protected by a mutex. (And I refuse to entirely trust said mutex to protect against the threat of undefined behavior associated with non-volatile reference access to volatile data.)

Comment: Then use `std::atomic <int >`  `volatile` gives no synchronisation guarantees _"...This makes volatile objects suitable for communication with a signal handler, but not with another thread of execution,..."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv

Comment: @RichardCritten Note that (4) is legit. By doing `(int)foo`, you first read `foo`. But, of course, the value of `foo` is of type `int` (not `volatile int`).

Comment: @RichardCritten How is (4) a `reinterpret_cast`? I thought only `const_cast` could cast away either const or volatile.

Comment: As @idmean pointed out I was wrong about (4).

Comment: @Idmean How does (4) map to the standard then? `(int)foo`, by itself, is just a cast, as far as I understand.

Comment: @RichardCritten I think I'm fine as far as inter-thread communications go, thank you. I'd rather understand the peculiarities of casting away `volatile` at a fundamental level. Not all questions are about solving a real-life problem.

Comment: Case (4) c-style cast tries the C++ casts  in order see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast  The 1st try being `const_cast` (fails), then `static_cast` which will read `foo` and create a temporary as @idmean said.

Comment: Looks like @idmean was close, but slightly off: Having dug a bit deeper in the other casts, it looks like `(int)foo` is actually mapped to `static_cast<int>(foo)`. And that, while not allowed to cast away constness, _is_ apparently allowed to cast away volatile-ness. Which does make sense, I guess.

Comment: @ChristophLipka - creates a temporary _"...returns the imaginary variable Temp initialized as if by new_type Temp(expression);..."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast

Comment: Pass by value is this way: `void Bar(int x)`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following casts are valid according to C++11, and should perform the desired operation by passing a reference to a temporary to the function:

```
Bar((int)foo);              // (4)
Bar(static_cast<int>(foo)); // (5)
```

As per section [expr.static.cast] of the standard (5.2.9 in C++11, specifically paragraph 4), (5) is valid, as `int t(foo);` is well-formed. A (non-volatile) temporary is created of that type, set to the volatile's current value, and a reference to this temporary is then passed to the function.

As per section [expr.cast] of the standard (5.4 in C++11, specifically paragraph 5.4), it follows that (4) is (or at least should be) entirely equivalent to (5).